# High amount of Request to yield per parsed page blocks crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a crawl where every subpage contains 300+ links which I need to follow.
The Crawl slows down after a minute or so / sometimes it crawls 0 pages / min.

If I rund the crawl with pages 10-50 links per page there same problem doesn't show.

I've configured 10 concurrent_requests and 10 processed items and reactor threadpool with 400. That means up to 3.000 yields per 10 processed items...

Logging shows that parse function takes 70+ seconds per page.
Logging shows that the time is needed here comes from the yields (take up to 2 seconds per yield).

It seems scrapy waits until the engine? or something similar has done one task and is ready to process the new yield request?
Adding the requests to scheduler don't take long so it seems to me that the yield is waiting for something other.

Any hints whats to tweak or whats going wrong?

Is it possible to yield the requests in bulk instead of yielding each on its own?
Is it possible to add them to scheduler without yielding them?

Some additional Informations:

- No difference if I use scrapy-redis or just disk-base scheduler.
- Because of rendering javascript a download of a crawled page can take up to 10 seconds.
- Autothrottle is disabled
- if I give more cpu ressources it doesn't speed up things.

```
telnet-> est()

    time()-engine.start_time                        : 676.0599975585938
    engine.has_capacity()                           : False
    len(engine.downloader.active)                   : 7
    engine.scraper.is_idle()                        : False
    engine.spider.name                              : onetwothree
    engine.spider_is_idle(engine.spider)            : False
    engine.slot.closing                             : False
    len(engine.slot.inprogress)                     : 28
    len(engine.slot.scheduler.dqs or [])            : AttributeError (exception)
    len(engine.slot.scheduler.mqs)                  : AttributeError (exception)
    len(engine.scraper.slot.queue)                  : 0
    len(engine.scraper.slot.active)                 : 21
    engine.scraper.slot.active_size                 : 3878605
    engine.scraper.slot.itemproc_size               : 0
    engine.scraper.slot.needs_backout()             : False
```

```
AttributeError seems to come from scrapy-redis plugin, 
without scrapy counts up the pages to request in mgs.
```

est if len(engine.downloader.active) goes to 0

```
    time()-engine.start_time                        : 7236.464096784592
    engine.has_capacity()                           : False
    len(engine.downloader.active)                   : 0
    engine.scraper.is_idle()                        : False
    engine.spider.name                              : onetwothree
    engine.spider_is_idle(engine.spider)            : False
    engine.slot.closing                             : False
    len(engine.slot.inprogress)                     : 25
    len(engine.slot.scheduler.dqs or [])            : AttributeError (exception)
    len(engine.slot.scheduler.mqs)                  : AttributeError (exception)
    len(engine.scraper.slot.queue)                  : 0
    len(engine.scraper.slot.active)                 : 25
    engine.scraper.slot.active_size                 : 5357134
    engine.scraper.slot.itemproc_size               : 0
    engine.scraper.slot.needs_backout()             : True
```

Crawler Code:

```py
    class robo2Spider(Spider):
        http_pass = None
        http_user = None
        dont_redirect = True
        start_urls = []
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    
            # ... some config ...
    
            self.start_urls = self.custom_settings["TEST_URLS"]
            # Don't Follow links in test mode
    
        def start_requests(self):
            for url in self.start_urls:
                r = self.get_request(url)
                yield r
    
        def parse(self, response):
            # some extraction and co...
            yield from self.scrape_data(response)
    
        def scrape_data(self, response):
            start_time = time.time()
    
            # more extraction, build item
    
            extract_links = util.extract_links_from_response(response, self.query_pars_to_ignore)
            logging.info(
                "--- logging time 1: %s --- %s seconds ---" % (response.url, time.time() - start_time))
    
            request_links = []
            for link in extract_links:
    
                if (not link["nofollow"]) and (l.get_output_value("crawl_meta_nofollow") != "nofollow"):
                    r = self.get_request(link["url"])
                    request_links.append(r)
    
            yield from request_links
    
            logging.info(
                "--- logging time 2 (takes up to 70 sec): %s --- %s seconds ---" % (response.url, time.time() - start_time))
    
            yield l.load_item()
    
    
        def get_request(self, url, rit=None, splash_retry=None):
    
            # ... setting meta & co ...
            meta = {}
            splash_args = {}
            return SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta=meta,
                                 args=splash_args, http_status_from_error_code=True,
                                 endpoint='execute', slot_policy=scrapy_splash.SlotPolicy.SCRAPY_DEFAULT)
```

Same result if i do it that way:

```py
    for link in extract_links:

        if (not link["nofollow"]) and (l.get_output_value("crawl_meta_nofollow") != "nofollow"):
            r = self.get_viu_request(link["url"])
            request_links.append(r)
            yield r
```

Comment: what does `get_viu_request` do? You should be timing that function instead your yield

Comment: see get_request / updated the code. Have timed this function also / it doesn't have any delay.
Have timed each step in 

    for link in extract_links:
        if (not link["nofollow"]) and (l.get_output_value("crawl_meta_nofollow") != "nofollow"):
            r = self.get_viu_request(link["url"])
            request_links.append(r)
            yield r
And it was the yield...

Comment: Yield delay is always ok. Because that is the way it is suppose to work. Doing a yield gives the control back to the main scrapy engine which then schedules other tasks in the queue and then after sometime comebacks to your function to move further. So what you are seeing is perfectly normal. Testing times across yields is not the right thing to do. It should always be before a yield

Comment: Hmm... Thanks. But that means, that the parse function runs up to 100 seconds. Didn't this blocking Scrapy to parse / crawl other things?

Comment: I think because your are using Splash, which in itself might be taking time to display and load the pages. Which kinds of slows down your requests

Comment: When the Crawler goes down to crawl 0 pages the len(engine.downloader.active) shows also 0. At that point it seams scrapy does nothing.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what `est()` outputs in addition to downloader.active == 0 when crawl gets to 0 pages

Comment: added est if crawl goes down to 0

Comment: Are you using proxies? If not, maybe that website just blocks your IP and does not respond

Comment: I catch if i get blocked / is not the case here. Also if the crawler gets blocked  it should download/timeout and then crawls next page or?

Comment: @MichaelWeber - I am seeing same issue. Were you able to solve it

Comment: I had the same issue. crawler becomes very slow when there are too many slots

Comment: Have you monitored your memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

`yield` performance is ideal, splash is what slows you down, try to get your data without using splash, check the network tab in the `devtools` to find the real request that loads your dynamic content to avoid using splash, if you can share a page that you are trying to scrape I can help you more to scrape it using pure scrapy with no splash or selenium needed.